# Swift - iOS - Dates and times in different format

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I am working for an application written in swift and i want to manipulate dates and times

```
let timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(
    NSDate(),
    dateStyle: .ShortStyle,
    timeStyle: .ShortStyle
)
```

returns

```
2/12/15, 11:27 PM
```

if I want date and time in a different format, for example the date in a European format like `dd/mm/yy` and the hours in the 24h format without AM and PM. Is there some function that i can use or i have to use N Strings to reorder the various elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current time as datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-as-datetime)

Answer (score 66):

```
func convertDateFormater(date: String) -> String {   
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

    guard let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date) else {
        assert(false, "no date from string")
        return ""
    }

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMM EEEE HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

    return timeStamp
}
```

Edit for Swift 4

```
func convertDateFormatter(date: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"//this your string date format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "your_loc_id")
    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

    guard dateFormatter.date(from: date) != nil else {
        assert(false, "no date from string")
        return ""
    } 

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MMM HH:mm EEEE"///this is what you want to convert format
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
    let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate!)

    return timeStamp
}
```

Comment: You should add more explanation for your answer. Just pasting the code is not stackoverflow style :)

Comment: This looks like a good approach, however the function requires the date input to be a String. Most times you'd be starting off with NSDate. What's the best way to format to String before passing into this function?

Comment: +1 for: dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Needed to manipulate date with timezones and using this worked like a charm to get formatter.string to formatter.date.

Answer (score 33):

As already mentioned you have to use DateFormatter to format your Date objects. The easiest way to do it is creating a read-only computed property Date extension.

---

> Read-Only Computed Properties
>
> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a
>   read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always
>   returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be
>   set to a different value.

**Note:**

> You must declare computed properties—including read-only computed
>   properties—as variable properties with the var keyword, because their
>   value is not fixed. The let keyword is only used for constant
>   properties, to indicate that their values cannot be changed once they
>   are set as part of instance initialization.
>
> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by
>   removing the get keyword and its braces:

---

```
extension Formatter {
    static let date = DateFormatter()
}
```

---

```
extension Date {
    var europeanFormattedEn_US : String {
        Formatter.date.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        Formatter.date.locale   = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        Formatter.date.timeZone = .current
        Formatter.date.dateFormat = "dd/M/yyyy, H:mm"
        return Formatter.date.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

To convert it back you can create another read-only computed property but as a string extension:

```
 extension String {
    var date: Date? {
        return Formatter.date.date(from: self)
    }
    func dateFormatted(with dateFormat: String = "dd/M/yyyy, H:mm", calendar: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601), defaultDate: Date? = nil, locale: Locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX"), timeZone: TimeZone = .current) -> Date? {
        Formatter.date.calendar = calendar
        Formatter.date.defaultDate = defaultDate ?? calendar.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())
        Formatter.date.locale = locale
        Formatter.date.timeZone = timeZone
        Formatter.date.dateFormat = dateFormat
        return Formatter.date.date(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let dateFormatted = Date().europeanFormattedEn_US         //"29/9/2018, 16:16"
if let date = dateFormatted.date {
    print(date.description(with:.current)) // Saturday, September 29, 2018 at 4:16:00 PM Brasilia Standard Time\n"\
    date.europeanFormattedEn_US                         // "29/9/2018, 16:27"
}
```

---

```
let dateString = "14/7/2016"
if let date = dateString.toDateFormatted(with: "dd/M/yyyy") {
    print(date.description(with: .current))
 // Thursday, July 14, 2016 at 12:00:00 PM Brasilia Standard Time\n"
}
```

Comment: Why an extension, something wrong with a simple method?

Comment: A different extension for each date format? Is an extension what a user would **expect**? Does the extension pass the is-a test? asDate is a String?

Comment: Get something else to do

Comment: I won't delete my answer because you don't like it

Comment: @Zaph I have added a method as you requested to customize the date format if needed. What else do you need ?

Answer (score 12):

As Zaph stated, you need to follow the documentation.  Admittedly it may not be the most straightforward when compared to other class references.  The short answer is, you use [Date Field Symbol Table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) to figure out what format you want.  Once you do:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
//the "M/d/yy, H:mm" is put together from the Symbol Table
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yy, H:mm"
dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

You'll also need to be able to use the table if you need to convert a date that is a string into an NSDate.

```
let dateAsString = "02/12/15, 16:48"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy, H:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString)
```

Answer (score 11):

Current date time to formated string:

```
let currentDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
let convertedDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate) //08/10/2016 01:42:22 AM
```

[More Date Time Formats](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html)

Answer (score 6):

Added some formats in one place. Hope someone get help.

**Xcode 12 - Swift 5.3**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
var dateFromStr = dateFormatter.date(from: "12:16:45")!

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a 'on' MMMM dd, yyyy"
//Output: 12:16:45 PM on January 01, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
//Output: Sat, 1 Jan 2000 12:16:45 +0600

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
//Output: 2000-01-01T12:16:45+0600

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy"
//Output: Saturday, Jan 1, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
//Output: 01-01-2000 12:16

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"
//Output: Jan 1, 12:16 PM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss.SSS"
//Output: 12:16:45.000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"
//Output: Jan 1, 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
//Output: 01/01/2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
//Output: 12:16:45 PM

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
//Output: January 2000

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yy"
//Output: 01.01.00

//Output: Customisable AP/PM symbols
dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "Pm"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "a"
//Output: Pm

// Usage
var timeFromDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromStr)
print(timeFromDate)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have already found `NSDateFormatter`, just read the documentation on it.

[NSDateFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html)

For format character definitions
See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)
Also: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table).

Answer (score 4):

### If you want to use protocol oriented programming (Swift 3)

**1) Create a Dateable protocol**

```
protocol Dateable {
    func userFriendlyFullDate() -> String
    func userFriendlyHours() -> String
}
```

**2) Extend Date class and implement the Dateable protocol**

```
extension Date: Dateable {
    var  formatter: DateFormatter { return DateFormatter() }

    /** Return a user friendly hour */
    func userFriendlyFullDate() -> String {
        // Customize a date formatter
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }

    /** Return a user friendly hour */
    func userFriendlyHours() -> String {
        // Customize a date formatter
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
 
    // You can add many cases you need like string to date formatter

}
```

**3) Use it**

```
let currentDate: Date = Date()
let stringDate: String = currentDate.userFriendlyHours()
// Print 15:16
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the a similar approach as @iod07, but as an extension.
Also, I added some explanations in the comments to understand how it works.

Basically, just add this at the top or bottom of your view controller.

```
extension NSString {

class func convertFormatOfDate(date: String, originalFormat: String, destinationFormat: String) -> String! {

    // Orginal format :
    let dateOriginalFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateOriginalFormat.dateFormat = originalFormat      // in the example it'll take "yy MM dd" (from our call)

    // Destination format :
    let dateDestinationFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateDestinationFormat.dateFormat = destinationFormat // in the example it'll take "EEEE dd MMMM yyyy" (from our call)

    // Convert current String Date to NSDate
    let dateFromString = dateOriginalFormat.dateFromString(date)

    // Convert new NSDate created above to String with the good format
    let dateFormated = dateDestinationFormat.stringFromDate(dateFromString!)

    return dateFormated

}
}
```

**Example**

Let's say you want to convert `"16 05 05"` to `"Thursday 05 May 2016"` and your date is declared as follow `let date = "16 06 05"`

Then simply call call it with :

```
let newDate = NSString.convertFormatOfDate(date, originalFormat: "yy MM dd", destinationFormat: "EEEE dd MMMM yyyy")
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: @Ideaman if you ask for help, please provide some details or explanations. What is your issue ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It says that dateFromString is nil

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that works with Xcode 10.1 (FEB 23 2019) :

```
func getCurrentDateTime() {

    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
    formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE dd MMMM YYYY"
    labelDate.text = formatter.string(from: now)
    labelDate.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
    labelDate.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

    let text = formatter.string(from: now)
    labelDate.text = text.uppercased()
}
```

[The "Accueil" Label is not connected to the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtFKa.png)

Comment: @mswyss Can we use a String to add multiple countries ("fr_FR", en_US", etc.) or do we need create a new line every time as you did?

Answer (score 3):

#### iOS 8+

It is cumbersome and difficult to specify `locale explicitly`. You never know where your app will be used. So I think, it is better to set `locale` to `Calender.current.locale`   and  use  `DateFormatter`'s
  `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` method.

#### setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:)

> Sets the date format from a template using the specified locale for the receiver. - [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla?language=objc)

```
extension Date {
    func convertToLocaleDate(template: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        let calender = Calendar.current

        dateFormatter.timeZone = calender.timeZone
        dateFormatter.locale = calender.locale
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(template)

        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}



Date().convertToLocaleDate(template: "dd MMMM YYYY")
```

Comment: I definitely is.
Apple on `dateFormat`: "You should only set this property when working with fixed format representations, as discussed in Working With Fixed Format Date Representations. For user-visible representations, you should use the dateStyle and timeStyle properties, or the setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:) method if your desired format cannot be achieved using the predefined styles; both of these properties and this method provide a localized date representation appropriate for display to the user."

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3:

```
//This gives month as three letters (Jun, Dec, etc)
let justMonth = DateFormatter()
justMonth.dateFormat = "MMM"
myFirstLabel.text = justMonth.string(from: myDate)

//This gives the day of month, with no preceding 0s (6,14,29)
let justDay = DateFormatter()
justDay.dateFormat = "d"
mySecondLabel.text = justDay.string(from: myDate)

//This gives year as two digits, preceded by an apostrophe ('09, '16, etc)
let justYear = DateFormatter()
justYear.dateFormat = "yy"
myThirdLabel.text = "'\(justYear.string(from: lastCompDate))"
```

For more formats, check out this [link](http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/) to a codingExplorer table with all the available formats. Each date component has several options, for example:

Year:

- "y" - 2016 (early dates like year 1 would be: "1")
- "yy" - 16 (year 1: "01"
- "yyy" - 2016 (year 1: "001")
- "yyyy" - 2016 (year 1: "0001")

Pretty much every component has 2-4 options, using the first letter to express the format (day is "d", hour is "h", etc). However, month is a capital "M", because the lower case "m" is reserved for minute. There are some other exceptions though, so check out the link!

Comment: Just want to add to get year as two digits with an apostrophe ('09, '16), the format is
''yy (two apostrophes)

Answer (score 2):

```
let usDateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(FromTemplate: "MMddyyyy", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
            //usDateFormat now contains an optional string "MM/dd/yyyy"

let gbDateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(FromTemplate: "MMddyyyy", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "en-GB"))
            //gbDateFormat now contains an optional string "dd/MM/yyyy"

let geDateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(FromTemplate: "MMddyyyy", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "de-DE"))
            //geDateFormat now contains an optional string "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

You can use it in following way to get the current format from device:

```
let currentDateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MMddyyyy", options: 0, locale: Locale.current)
```

Comment: I think that's probably the correct answer as you really should not use `dateFormat` directly, like others do.
Apple:
"You should only set this property when working with fixed format representations, as discussed in Working With Fixed Format Date Representations. For user-visible representations, you should use the dateStyle and timeStyle properties, or the setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:) method if your desired format cannot be achieved using the predefined styles; both of these properties and this method provide a localized date representation appropriate for display to the user."

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateString = "1970-01-01T13:30:00.000Z"
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let date = formatter.date(from: String(dateString.dropLast(5)))!
formatter.dateFormat = "hh.mma"
print(formatter.string(from: date))
```

if You notice I have set `.dateFormat = "hh.mma"`by this you will get time only.
Result:`01.30PM`

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {

    func convertDatetring_TopreferredFormat(currentFormat: String, toFormat : String) ->  String {
        let dateFormator = DateFormatter()
        dateFormator.dateFormat = currentFormat
        let resultDate = dateFormator.date(from: self)
        dateFormator.dateFormat = toFormat
        return dateFormator.string(from: resultDate!)
    }

}
```

Call from your view controller file as below.

```
"your_date_string".convertDatetring_TopreferredFormat(currentFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s", toFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly an old thread but I was working on datetimes recently and was stuck with similar issue so I ended up creating a utility of mine which looks like this,

This utility would take a string date and would return an optional date object

```
        func toDate(dateFormat: DateFormatType) -> Date? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone?
        formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat.rawValue
        let temp = formatter.date(from: self)
        return formatter.date(from: self)
        }
```

the `DateFormatType` enum looks like this

```
        enum DateFormatType : String {
        case type1 = "yyyy-MM-dd - HH:mm:ss"
        case type2 = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        case type3 = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    }
```

One important thing I would like to mention here is the line

`formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone?`

it's very important that you add this line because without this the `DateFormatter` would use it's default conversions to convert the date and you might end up seeing different dates if you are working with a remote team and get all sorts of issues with data depending on dates.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

## Time Picker In swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //timePicker
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelTime_Btn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var donetime_Btn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    
    //Date picker
//    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ishidden(bool: true)
        let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "HH:mm a" //"hh:mm a"
        lblTime.text = dateFormatter2.string(from: timePicker.date)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func selectTime_Action(_ sender: Any) {
        timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
        ishidden(bool: false)
    }
    
    @IBAction func timeCancel_Action(_ sender: Any) {
        ishidden(bool: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func timeDoneBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter1.dateFormat =  "HH:mm a"//"hh:mm"
        
        let str = dateFormatter1.string(from: timePicker.date)
        lblTime.text = str
        
        ishidden(bool: true)
        
    }
    
    func ishidden(bool:Bool){
           timePicker.isHidden = bool
           toolBar.isHidden = bool
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date(year,month,day,0,0,0,0)` is local time (as input)
`new Date(year,month,day)` is UTC

I was using a function to attain `YYYY-MM-DD` format to be compatible on iOS web, **but that is also UTC when used in comparisons** (not chained by getFullYear or similar) I've found it is best to use only the above with strong (hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds) building a calendar, calculating with a Date objects and local references

```
export const zeroPad = (num) => {
  var res = "0";
  if (String(num).length === 1) {
    res = `0${num}`;
  } else {
    res = num;
  }
  return res;
};
```