# Modify date format of a string

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to modify the date format of a string in Swift.

I need to print my date to the french format :

> 17 mai 2015

I tried this :

```
var myDate = "2015-05-17 13:00:00"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM"
var readableDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDate)
println("Readable date = \(readableDate!)")
```

I obtain a `nil` value when I run the program, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Look at any of the ten thousand prior questions on this topic.  (Or, horror of horrors, actually read the documentation.)

Comment: If you have `myDate` as a string, then you really need two formatters, one to convert this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` string to a `NSDate` object, and another to convert that `NSDate` back into a string in your french format. And for this latter formatter, I might suggest you do not specify any `dateFormat` string and just specify a `dateStyle`, and let it represent the date in a format dictated by the end user's localization settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - IOS - Dates and times in different format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489227/swift-ios-dates-and-times-in-different-format)

Comment: Also, it's not clear from your question as to whether the time in this original string is in the end-user's local time zone or GMT. So you might want to confirm that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.dateFromString`creates an NSDate() from a String. The format of the string has to be set with `.dateFormat`

You set the format to "d MMMM" but your `myDate` variable does not conform to that format.

I believe you want to make a String in your "d MMMM" format out of a date.
Take this code as a starting-point:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM"
var readableDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
println("Readable date = \(readableDate)")
```

Check out the [Class Reference for NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html) for further assistance

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please tag the answer as correct after you tried