# How do I make more than one date format in a single view in Swift?

Tags: swift, date, swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to save data to a database and am using a date that shows seconds as the key but I want to show a smaller date in the value that is going to be displayed. The problem is to use the date formatter you need to set it like this and I cant figure out how to set another one without overwriting the current format.

```
DateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy hh:mm:ss a"
```

Comment: You can create multiple DateFormatter objects. Various examples can be found on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489227/swift-ios-dates-and-times-in-different-format).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - iOS - Dates and times in different format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489227/swift-ios-dates-and-times-in-different-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to have multiple `DateFormatter` in a single View.

## Formatter1

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "QQQQ\ryyyy" //Shows Financial Quarter for Date
 let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: date)
```

## Formatter2

```
let formatter1 = DateFormatter()
 formatter1.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy" //Wednesday, Mar 29, 2017
 let formattedDate1 = formatter1.string(from: date)
```

Refer to this site to know more about [DateFormatter](http://nsdateformatter.com/). Hope this helps. Happy Coding !