# How to record date, time, and score in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am creating a simple quiz app. I am planning to show some kind of "history" where the user can see the following:

1. Date and time of playing
2. Score for that particular session

How do I do that?

As of the Date and Time of playing, I saw this thread on SO: [How to get the current time as datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-and-hour-as-datetime)
However, how do I "RECORD" the date(s) and time(s) the user played the game?

Regarding the Score data, I am using:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(currentScore, forKey: "score")
```

However, I am only able to get the CURRENT SCORE. How do I record the score(s) the user got for EACH session on different date(s) and time(s)?

Please note that I have no problem in getting the user's CURRENT SCORE. I need help in storing or recording the user's score(s) in multiple sessions.

For instance, I wanted to display something like this:

```
Date: 2/7/16
Time: 7:00 AM
Score: 70/100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` probably isn't right for what you are trying to do. I recommend using `NSCoding` for simple data storing. Core Data may be too complicated for something this simple. However, if you plan on saving a large data model with relationships, Core Data is the way to go.

## NSCoding

`NSCoding` has two parts:

1. Encoding and decoding
2. Archiving and unarchiving

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) explains this perfectly:

> NSCoding is a simple protocol, with two methods: -initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder:. Classes that conform to NSCoding can be serialized and deserialized into data that can be either be archived to disk or distributed across a network.

That archiving is performed by `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

### Session

Even without `NSCoding`, it is suggested to represent data with objects. In this case, we can use the very creative name `Session` to represent a session in the history.

```
class Session: NSObject, NSCoding {

    let date: NSDate // stores both date and time
    let score: Int

    init(date: NSDate, score: Int) { // initialize a NEW session

        self.date = date
        self.score = score

        super.init()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // decodes an EXISTING session

        if let decodedDate = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("date") as? NSDate {
             self.date = decodedDate
        } else {
             self.date = NSDate() // placeholder // this case shouldn't happen, but clearing compiler errors
        }

        self.score = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("score")

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encodeObject(date, forKey: "date")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(score, forKey: "score")

    }

}
```

The above code in English, in order from top to bottom:

- Defining the class, conforming to `NSCoding`
- The properties of a session: the date (+ time) and the score
- The initializer for a new session - simply takes a date and score and creates an session for it
- The required initializer for an existing session - decodes the date and score that is saved

  - `decodeObjectForKey:` simply does what it says (decodes an object using a key), and it returns `AnyObject?`
  - `decodeIntegerForKey:`, however, returns `Int`. If none exists on file, it returns 0, which is why it isn't optional. This is the case for most of the decoding methods except for `decodeObjectForKey:`
- The required method for encoding an existing session - encodes the date and score

  - The encoding methods are just as straightforward as the decoding methods.

That takes care of the `Session` class, with the properties ready for `NSCoding`. Of course, you could always add more properties and methods.

### SessionHistory

While the sessions itself are nice, an object to manage the array of sessions is needed, and it also needs to conform to `NSCoding`. You could also add this code to an existing class.

```
class SessionHistory: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var sessions = [Session]()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        if let decodedSessions = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("sessions") as? [Session] {
             self.sessions = decodedSessions
        } else {
             self.sessions = [] // another compiler error clearer
        }

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encodeObject(sessions, forKey: "sessions")

    }

    override init() { // Used for convenience
        super.init()
    }

}
```

English translation:

- Defining the manager, conforming to `NSCoding`
- Add property for the array of sessions
- Next two `NSCoding` methods do nearly the same thing as `Session`. Except this time, it is with an array.
- Initializer for a new manager, which will be used below.

`NSCoding` looks at this manager class and sees that it needs to encode an array of sessions, so then `NSCoding` looks at the `Session` class to see what to encode for those sessions.

### NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver and Singletons

While all the `NSCoding` is set up now, the final step is to incorporate `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to actually save and load the data.

The two important methods are `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(_, toFile:)` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveRootObjectWithFile:`

Note that both methods need a file. It automagically creates the file for you, but you need to set a location. Add this to `SessionHistory`:

```
static var dataPath: String {

    let URLs = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let URL = URLs[0]
    return URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("savehistory").path! // Put anything you want for that string

}
```

That simply finds a location for the file. You could, of course, find somewhere else to put the file.

With the data path ready, you can use the two methods I mentioned earlier. I like to use a modified version of a singleton for the manager class to make sure I'm using the same array of objects. In the `SessionHistory` class:

```
private static var history: SessionHistory!

static func appHistory() -> SessionHistory {

    if history == nil {
        if let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(dataPath) as? SessionHistory {
            history = data
        } else {
            history = SessionHistory()
        }
    }

    return history

}
```

This creates a private static property to store the one session history of the app. The static method checks if the session history is `nil`. If so, it returns the current history on file and loads the file into the history property. Otherwise, it creates a new empty session history. After that, or if the history property already stores something, it returns the history property.

### Usage

All the setup for `NSCoding` and `NSKeyedArchiver` is done. But how do you use this code?

Each time you want to access the session history, call

```
SessionHistory.appHistory()
```

Wherever you want to save the session history, call

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(SessionHistory.appHistory(), toFile: SessionHistory.dataPath)
```

Sample usage would work like this:

```
let session = Session(date: someRandomDate, score: someRandomScore)
SessionHistory.appHistory().sessions.append(session)
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(SessionHistory.appHistory(), toFile: SessionHistory.dataPath)
```

The session history will automatically be loaded from the file when accessed via `SessionHistory.appHistory()`.

You don't really need to "link" the classes per se, you just need to append the sessions to the `sessions` array of the session history.

### Further Reading

- [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/) is a good, simple introduction to `NSCoding`.
- [Apple's NSCoding guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/), although older and in Objective-C, goes deeper into `NSCoding`.

Comment: Hi, may you pls help me on how do I actually "use" the codes that you gave above? How do I "link" between these classes? thanks!

Comment: @mjoe7 I completely re-edited my post. Maybe that will clean things up :)

Comment: thanks for your help. I will try it now and let you know. :)

Comment: I created the SessionHistory class and I got the following 2 errors: "Type 'SessionHostory' does not conform to protocol 'NSCoding' and "Value of type 'NSCoding' has no member 'encodeObject'"

Comment: @mjoe7 Sorry, I made one little mistake on my part. The parameter type is supposed to be `NSCoder` not `NSCoding`. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

To store scores for each session, you'll need some sort of data structure associated with each user. You could use a dictionary of key value pairs that associates a date with a score. That way you would have a score for each date stored for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a database to store such data with an undefined count of records.
Check out the Core Data Programming Guide by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)

You could then create an entity named `history` where you store records of the user's game play history, by inserting a new object into the entity every time the user finishes a game.

When you need to show the results, you'd create an `NSFetchRequest` over an `NSManagedObjectContext` to get all the results and display/filter them as you'd like.

Hope that helps!