# How to get the specific date in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a project where I have labels and images that change on a daily basis. My idea on how to go about this is I add assets for the images and have multiple files where I take the text (that contains the quote).

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way of approaching this? (I'm fairly new to iOS, so I'm wondering if this is sound).
2. How can I take the current day as in: May 22? (I just want to know how to get "22").

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please help other people to help you by following these guidelines when asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `NSDate`

```
// Option 1
let date = NSDate() // today
let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
let d = dateStringFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
// d = "22"

// Option 2
let d = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day, fromDate: NSDate()) // thanks Leo-Dabus
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/

Comment: Im getting error messages from this, is their anything I need to import?

Comment: maybe `UIKit` (it's what I imported), also remove `!` on the last line

Comment: None of this code requires UIKit. These classes are in Foundation.

Comment: @Nick3150 `NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day, fromDate: NSDate())`

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look at this stackoverflow link on getting the current date.

[How to get the current time as datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-and-hour-as-datetime)

According to noliv in the article you should be able do :

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```

Hope this helps