# How to calculate how much time passed from the date with timezone?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdate

I get from the server a date with this format:

```
2016-05-27 17:33:43+0400
```

Now, I want to detect, how much time passed since that date? For example `1 day 5 hours 10 minutes 20 seconds`.

How can I do it? I know how to calculate this from the timestamp, but do not know how to convert this to a timestamp.

Can anyone help me with it?

**For example:**

Convert this `2016-05-27 17:33:43+0400` to `1464370423` this

Or maybe there are another solution. I just want to calculate how much time passed since that time

Comment: What do you mean "convert to timestamp"?  Can you show what output you want and what you have so far?

Comment: @Paulw11 I've edited my question and added this: For example, Convert this `2016-05-27 17:33:43+0400` to `1464370423` this

Or maybe there are another solution. I just want to calculate how many time passed since that time(how many days, hours, minutes, seconds)

Comment: Take a look at NSDateFormatter, it allows you to convert NSDate to/from string formats.  Once you have an NSDate, you seem to be looking for https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/timeIntervalSince1970

Comment: What is `1464370423`?

Comment: @Paulw11 timestamp

Comment: @Paulw11 I just converted my date to timestamp. I do not get your question. Maybe you can help me to calculate those time distance in another way?

Comment: Oh ok.  It is a `timeIntervalSince1970`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSDateComponents formatter to get the relative time between two dates. Regarding the date string format you need to use `xx` for the time zone part.

```
let dateStr = "2016-05-27 17:33:43+0400"

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssxx"
formatter.calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateStr) {
    print(date)   // "2016-05-27 13:33:00 +0000\n" -4hs
    let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.Day,.Hour,.Minute,.Second]
    dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .Full
    print(dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromDate(date, toDate: NSDate()) ?? "") // 6 days, 17 hours, 51 minutes, 29 seconds
}
```

Comment: It seems that NSDateFormatter is pretty forgiving.  It works with ZZZ ZZZZ ZZZZZ or xx

Answer (score 1):

given the input string you can convert it to a date and subsequently to an `NSTimeInterval` since the current time using the following.

```
let inputDate = "2016-05-27 17:33:43+0400"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

if let aDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(inputDate) {

    let timeInterval = aDate.timeIntervalSinceNow

    let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()

    if let dateString = dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(abs(timeInterval)) {

        print ("Elapsed time=\(dateString)")
    }
}
```

Output:

> Elapsed time=6d 17:51:52

You can get the date as the timestamp in your question using `aDate.timeIntervalSince1970`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that this could help you: [How to get the current time as datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-and-hour-as-datetime)

You can get the current time and calculate the difference using the server time and your current time.

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you

> "how many time"

passed since an event.

```
let date = Date()
let howManyTimePassed = date.timeIntervalSinceNow
```

`TimeInterval` is a `typealias` for a `double`, meaning its another way to say `double`. The value of the `timeInterval` represents seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this class in **Swift 5.1**:

```
open class MyDateClass: NSObject {

    private var result:MyDateTime!
    
     init(dateStr: String, inputFormat: String) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = inputFormat //"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        if let date = formatter.date(from: dateStr) {
            let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
            dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second]
            dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .full
            let strFromat = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: date, to: Date()) ?? ""
            var trimmedString = strFromat.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            trimmedString = trimmedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "years", with: "")
            trimmedString = trimmedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "months", with: "")
            trimmedString = trimmedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "days", with: "")
            trimmedString = trimmedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "hours", with: "")
            trimmedString = trimmedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "minutes", with: "")
            trimmedString = trimmedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "seconds", with: "")
            let arr = trimmedString.split(separator: ",")
            let result = MyDateTime(year: Int(arr[0]), month: Int(arr[1]), day: Int(arr[2]), hour: Int(arr[3]), minute: Int(arr[4]), second: Int(arr[5]))
            self.result = result
        }
    }
    
    func getDateTime() -> MyDateTime {
        return result
    }
      
}

public struct MyDateTime {
    var year:Int?
    var month:Int?
    var day:Int?
    var hour:Int?
    var minute:Int?
    var second:Int?
}
```

And this class works like this:

```
let myClass = MyDateClass(dateStr: "2016-05-27 17:33:43", inputFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
let time = myClass.getDateTime()
```

Now you can show time as you wish.