# Difference between NSCalendar.current and NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

Tags: swift3, nscalendar

I'm working on accessing healthkit's Heartrate data and through following the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hksamplequery. They call to use the following code snippet

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let now = NSDate()
let components = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day], fromDate: now)
```

However the debugger catches the NSCalendar.currentCalendar() as cannot call value of non-function type calendar. I changed it to NSCalendar.current as suggested by the IDE however then the third line has a problem stating that it cannot use instance member 'calendar' within property initializer.

So my question is what is the difference between NSCalendar.current and NSCalendar.currentCalendar() and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much for any help that you can provide.

Comment: You need to convert to Swift 3. You are feeding Swift 2 code to the Swift 3 compiler. That's not going to work. They are different languages. Use Calendar, Date, and all their new properties and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you are using Swift 3 but looking at instructions for Swift 2.x. The APIs have changed. This is the Swift 3 equivalent:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: now)
```

Comment: Swift 3 you should use Calendar instead of NSCalendar

Comment: Thanks so much that helped! But it seems like the third line still has an issue: Cannot use instance member 'calendar' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248941/how-to-get-time-hour-minute-second-in-swift-3-using-nsdate