# cannot convert value of type date to expected argument type date

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift 3 and trying to get the current hour. Below is the code i have written to get the current hour but it gives an error.

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date) // error
```

What could be the reason for this, all the sample code based on Swift 3 shows the same code snippet to get the current hour but it just don't seem to work. Please can anyone point out what could be wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: Compiles fine for me – I would hazard a guess that you've defined your own `Date` type which is shadowing Foundation's `Date`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: its works perfectly

Comment: @Hamish : this is the only code I have written , It somehow seems to be a bug in my Xcode as it is showing me random errors and to get rid of it i often have to rebuild and clean the project.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 8 and Swift 3? Try creating a new playground containing only this code.

Comment: Yes I am using xcode 8 with swift 3. OK will try creating a new project.

Comment: Please check [How to get time (hour, minute, second) in Swift 3 using NSDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248941/how-to-get-time-hour-minute-second-in-swift-3-using-nsdate)

Comment: Hamish: you were so right I indeed had made a class named Date which was shadowing Foundation's Date class.  Coming from java background I pretty much used to seeing all my imports at the top of the file itself unlike swift which induced the error . Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code to get hour in swift 3 :

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from:  NSDate() as Date)
```

Comment: In Swift 3.0 Apple removed 'NS' prefix and made everything simple

Answer (score -3):

Use this code to get a current hour:

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.setFormat = "h"
print(formatter.stringFromDate(date))
```

Note: I did not run this code in xcode so don't just copy paste.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue in the question.