# Calculate "Start" Time from "End" Time

Tags: swift, date, time

I'm working to create a function that takes an input duration and an "end" time, and calculates a "start" time based on that criteria.

Example: if the "end" time is 5:00pm and the "duration" is 30 minutes, then the "start" time returned should be 4:30pm.

I'm getting lost in translating between Int/Date/String, so I may need to re-think my entire approach.  So far I'm working with the following, which is just a take on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248941/how-to-get-time-hour-minute-second-in-swift-3-using-nsdate):

```
var userInputEventEndTime: String
var userInputEventDuration: Int
var userInputEventNeedsToStartTime: String

//Manipulate this function with the input parameters
 func makeDate(hr: Int, min: Int, sec: Int) -> Date {
    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = DateComponents(hour: hr, minute: min, second: sec)
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: calendar.date(from: components)!)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: calendar.date(from: components)!)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: calendar.date(from: components)!)
    return calendar.date(from: components)!
}
```

Should I be converting the input strings to DateComponents and then doing the math?  If so, I'm not sure how to account for minutes converting to hours.  Or just go a different direction altogether?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your event only given as a time without a date part?

Comment: Correct; no year/month/day context necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses DateComponents and Calendar to calculate the start time

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, minute: -userInputEventDuration)

if let endTime = dateFormatter.date(from: userInputEventEndTime),
    let startTime = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: endTime, wrappingComponents: false) {
    userInputEventNeedsToStartTime = dateFormatter.string(from: startTime)
}
```

Here is the same solution written as a function with an example

```
func calculateStartTime(from endTime: String, duration: Int) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, minute: -duration)
    if let time = dateFormatter.date(from: endTime),
        let startTime = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: time, wrappingComponents: false) {
        return dateFormatter.string(from: startTime)
    }

    return nil
}

if let startTime = calculateStartTime(from: "6:00 PM", duration: 30) {
    print("Event starts at \(startTime)")
}
```

Output

> Event starts at 05:30 PM

Answer (score 0):

To subtract components from the date, just add their negative values.