# Adding a self populating date into the Navigation Bar Title

Tags: ios, swift, datetime

I want to have the current date prepopulate in the navigation bar each time the user opens the app, without having to select it using the date picker. Similar to how food tracker apps such as Lose It and MyFitness Pal work.  But I can't find any documentation on how to do this. Here's what I tried but it says I can't assign NSDate to type String.

```
let currentDate = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

 dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
    var convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"
    convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)

    self.title = NSDate()
```

Comment: `NSDate()` will give a date object set to the current date and time. `NSDateFormatter` is used to get string representations of dates

Comment: You'll want something like `self.title = NSDate()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current time (and hour) as datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-and-hour-as-datetime)

Comment: Hi @WMios I converted current date to a string as described above but it's not letting me assign it to the title saying it's still not a string.  I added my code above thx :)

Comment: It needs to be "/(NSDate())" or String(NSDate())

Comment: @WMios ok String(NSDate()) worked I didn't realize I was actually putting it in a print format BUT one more issue.  I'm getting 2016-09-12 15:40:06+0000 even though I've specified the format I want above.  I took out the redundancy .FullStyle but there's still no change.

Comment: Yeah so you want to make self.title equal to your formatted date.

Comment: @WMios I'm sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Just do `self.title = convertedDate`

Comment: @WMios wow thank you so much!!! I  feel like such a dummy lol.

Comment: @WMios is there a way to contact you? I'm looking for someone I can pay for simple help just like this.

Comment: @M.J., if you want, click on my username and go to my profile and I have a link to my site that has a contact page. I don't want to post info here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you need to assign `self.title` the correct date value.

The line:

```
self.title = NSDate()
```

is assigning `self.title` to a new instance of `NSDate()`, while you want to assign it to the formatted date that you have above, `convertedDate, which is also a`String`.

Additionally, `NSDate()` is of type `NSDate` and not of type `String`. If you converted it to a `String` it would be *unformatted*.

So really, you need the line to be:

```
self.title = convertedDate
```