# Get current date in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, nsdate

How can I set label.text current date in Swift 3?

I want to print just today to the screen. I did not find how to do that.

In c# is very simple:

```
var date = DateTime.Now
```

I need to write 15.09.2016 in swift 3.
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-and-hour-as-datetime

Comment: thats not working any more?

Comment: Did you scroll all the way to the bottom for the Swift 3 answer?

Comment: I tried but I didnt make it

Comment: You probably want to use an `NSDateFormatter` and then `stringFromDate`.

Comment: I just want to print screen this 15.09.2016
label.text = "15.09.2016"

Comment: If only it were that simple

Answer (score 314, accepted):

You say in a comment you want to get "15.09.2016".

For this, use `Date` and `DateFormatter`:

```
let date = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
```

Give the format you want to the formatter:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
```

Get the result string:

```
let result = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Set your label:

```
label.text = result
```

Result:

> 15.09.2016

Comment: In Swift 4.2, DateFormatter has both .dateStyle and .timeStyle properties. Instead of the somewhat opaque syntax above (which gives more fine-grained control - see https://nsdateformatter.com) you can use dateStyle combined with locale.

Answer (score 72):

You can do it in this way with Swift 3.0:

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)

let year =  components.year
let month = components.month
let day = components.day

print(year)
print(month)
print(day)
```

Comment: I cannot believe even after Swift 3 that date handling is so bad!  It's shameful considering Date in .NET was in version 1 in 2002 from memory.
DateTime.Now or DateTime.Now.Month are so much easier!

Comment: How do you know if that day is a Mon, Tue, or Wed?

Comment: Check out SwiftDate Cocoapod if you'd like a much easier way to interact with dates in swift.

Comment: @csmith That's because its still the old NSDate but with Swift syntax. It hasn't been rewritten. You're right though, it is a bit of a pain to work with.