# iOS - Calculate Running time and distance

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

I am working on personal health assistance application where I have to calculate some data such as walking steps, time and distance. Similar for running and automotive(when user is riding on vehicle). This will collect data w.r.t time - collect device data.

For walking I have used CMPedometer to calculate distance and steps (though could  not find any help in measuring time).

But for calculating running distance and time I did not find any help. I have tried with *CMMotionActivityManager* but *CMMotionActivity* only returns the activity type (running or automotive) and start time no end time or any distance.

Please help me to find a solution to get this data without running the app in foreground.

thank you

Comment: you can get current time to start and end 
see more : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24070837/3992606

Comment: @mohsen thank you for your reply, actually it is not about time conversion. I need to get the measurement of various activity like running or automotive