# How to scroll UICollectionView cell automatically according to the time of day

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am creating a small application that displays the bus timetables of my city. I use a UICollectionView to display all the timetables:

From 06:00 in the morning to 00:30 in the evening. Buses pass every 30 min.

I would like my cells to scroll automatically according to the time of the day, even if the application is closed. I would like my the cells that display the next bus (e.g. 2:30 pm) display the one at 2:00 pm and automatically scroll after 2:30 pm to display the next bus that comes at 3:00 pm etc... until 00:30 am. And after 00:30, I would like to display the cell that shows 06:00. And the process continues ad infinitum.

```
extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return busHoursList.count
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let busCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "busCellID", for: indexPath) as! BusCollectionViewCell
    busCell.layer.borderWidth = 0.6
    busCell.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    busCell.layer.borderColor = CGColor.init(red: 170/250, green: 170/250, blue: 170/250, alpha: 1)
    busCell.setupDepartureHours(withText: busDepartureHoursList[indexPath.row])
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- the solution I propose is you create a function that runs when opening the application, with it you capture the current time and then you adjust the data of your collection to the current time.

2- after that you can run an asynchronous function to synchronize with the current time and make this update while the application is running think about this code base for that

```
 Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval, repeats: true) { timer in
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how do you adjust the data of the collection to the current time ? Sorry, I'm a complete novice in swift.

Comment: I think this can be useful
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070450/how-to-get-the-current-time-as-datetime)