# Convert NSDate to an Integer

Tags: ios, integer, nsdate

So my dilemma is that I can't figure out how to store the date only in an integer value (fetched using:

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date]
```

I found this code online which seems similar to what I need (I thought that changing setDateFormat to @"dd" would've worked (but apparently it didn't)

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

//Optionally for time zone conversions
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Am I just forgetting something simple about integers?

Comment: `–timeIntervalSince1970`, then `– initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:`. the actual `NSTimeInterval` is a regular `double` but you can convert it to `NSInteger` if you don't need the fragment part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dd` in `setDateFormat:`.

This will give only date but in string.

After this you can convert the string to integer, with the help of `integerValue`.

Edit:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];


NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger integerDate = [stringFromDate integerValue];
```

Comment: So just like [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];?

I tried that before to no avail

Edit: Do you know how to store it in an Integer?

Comment: @CallMeGreeny: check the full implementation

Comment: @AnoopVaidya if it is possible to convert NSDate to NSInteger directly without NSString?

Comment: @SmitSaraiya: No! You can remove the intermediate string variable if you don't want to have it. `NSInteger integerDate = [[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] integerValue];`

Answer (score 5):

**Swift**

### `NSDate` to `Int`

```
// using current date and time as an example
let someNSDate = NSDate() 

// convert NSDate to NSTimeInterval (typealias for Double)
let timeInterval = someNSDate.timeIntervalSince1970

// convert to Integer
let myInt = Int(timeInterval)
```

Doing the `Double` to `Int` conversion causes the milliseconds to be lost. If you need the milliseconds then multiply by 1000 before converting to `Int`.

### `Int` to `NSDate`

Including the reverse for completeness.

```
// convert Int to Double
let timeInterval = Double(myInt)

// create NSDate from Double (NSTimeInterval)
let myNSDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval)
```

I could have also used `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` instead of `timeIntervalSince1970` as long as I was consistent. This is assuming that the time interval is in seconds. Note that Java uses milliseconds.

### Update

As of Swift 3, the conversion would use `Date` rather than `NSDate`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39934058/3681880) for the Swift 3 version.

Comment: `timeIntervalSince1970` should be accepted as the appropriate answer instead of spinning up an `NSDateFormatter`, creating a string, and then parsing that string to an integer. It just makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Although I believe the original poster was looking for just the 'days' part of the date, I imagine that given the title, others will come to this question looking for a way to convert a date to a canonical integer representation (for example, milliseconds since the epoch).

The Cocoa date library stores dates as a floating point number of seconds since `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001`.

To get this value, call `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]`. To get the number of seconds (floating point) since the Unix epoch, call `[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]`. To get milliseconds, simply multiply by 1000.

So, to get the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, as an integer:

`(NSInteger)round([NSDate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)`